# Questions about software packages?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about what polygon clipping libraries might be available for C# .NET 4.5, and I'm not sure what forum would be best to ask in.

I'd normally ask in StackOverflow, but I'm not sure that it's a good fit. Is there another StackExchange site that would be better suited?

Comment: Even if you'd find a stack site where the question wouldn't be off-topic, I would be surprised if anyone actually knew what you would be looking for if you'd just ask about a "polygon clipping library". That sounds more like a math requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of a software recommendation, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Try asking on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead, as long as you follow [their own guidelines for asking questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).